# Converting SVG with Embedded CSS to PDF in Python

Tags: python, svg, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate a PDF image from an SVG image using Python. I've tried both [CairoSVG](http://cairosvg.org) and [svglib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/). The problem is that in both cases the generated PDFs do not have any of the embedded CSS styles applied.

Here is a simple SVG file which should render a blue rectangle with a black border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
      rect {
        fill: #1f77b4;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
    ]]></style>
  </defs>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

When rendering a PDF of this SVG using CairoSVG, the PDF image is rendered as a black rectangle. Using svglib, there is no stroke or style applied to the rectangle so it is not visible. Is anyone aware of a way to convert an SVG **with CSS styles** to a PDF image in Python?

Comment: I have to make thumbnails for D3 visualizations, so far the best I came up is a somewhat convoluted setup using phantomjs to render the SVG. Since phantomjs is a real webkit browser, the SVG is rendered exactly like the browser version (there is a phantompy module but it is segfaulting in my environment and I lack the time to investigate the reason).

Comment: The CairoSVG documentation has this note: CairoSVG can use lxml to parse the SVG file, and tinycss plus cssselect to apply CSS not included in the style attribute of the tags. If these packages are not available, CSS will only be supported in the style attributes.  IF you install the tinycss and cssselect packages it might solve your problem.  See the Dependencies section here: http://cairosvg.org/user_documentation/

Comment: @MonkeyWrench: it is the best tip so far, if you care you can make it an answer and collect the bounty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(With help from @MonkeyWrench, since he didn't post an answer.)

According to the [documentation](http://cairosvg.org/user_documentation/),

> CairoSVG can use lxml to parse the SVG file, and tinycss plus cssselect to apply CSS not included in the style attribute of the tags. If these packages are not available, CSS will only be supported in the style attributes.

To get started, I installed all the dependencies,

```
$ pip3 install cairosvg lxml tinycss cssselect
```

Then I created `image.svg` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
      rect {
        fill: #1f77b4;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }
    ]]></style>
  </defs>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Finally, I executed cairosvg

```
$ cairosvg image.svg -o image.pdf
```

And sure enough, it was a blue rectangle.

[image: blue]

Comment: Has example, gave credit, everything checks. Nice job, collect your bounty. :-)

Comment: Glad it worked out.  Have been away for a while.  Better keep up in the future.

Comment: Just to understand the solution better - What's the benefit of this approach as compared to using PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the style attribute instead?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="100" height="100"
  style="fill:#1f77b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;shape-rendering: crispEdges;"
  stroke-opacity:0.9"/>
</svg>
```

It's ultimately the same as you have already, but maybe CairoSVG skips over style elements in your HTML.

Comment: This markup gets rendered correctly by both CairoSVG and svglib. However, I'm trying to convert SVG images as rendered on a web page. It's not practical to apply style attributes to each individual element. Even though this won't work for my situation, this is useful info. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Basically it's a headless WebKit, driven by Javascript.

Look into the [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) script.

You can grab the coordinates and export (rasterize) that section as an image. Then you can use basically any PDF generator, by embedding the image. Alternatively, you can use another script to generate the PDF file with PhantomJS.

Comment: `rasterize.js` can generate PDFs, no need for external generators.